# Why does Safari detect a circular reference that Firefox does not?

Tags: javascript

The circular reference found when running `JSON.stringify.`

The object in which it detects the circular reference looks like this in the console.

```
LOG|ES5|Object>>{
 "state": true,
 "model": "MAppAMDeleter",
 "client": {},
 "time": {},
 "bin": {
  "arg_this": {},        // I'm guessing this is the culprit
  "foo_id": "610"
 },
 "server": {
  "smalls": {
   "name": "The Foos",
   "page": "ma",
   "h_token": "1FOO",
   "remember": "0",
   "pane": "",
   "privacy": "0",
   "h_file": "1FOO",
   "picture": "1",
   "special": "0"
  },
  "tweets": {},
 }
}
```

The only thing that I believe could cause the error is this line where I actually assign to the object literal.

```
pipe.bin.arg_this = this; // when I assign this, it points to a different object all together.
```

I'm trying to understand why Safari would suppose that it points to the object literal containing structured data ( the one I copied above ) while Firefox seems to know that it refers to the initial object in which I assigned it - actually a page element.

Comment: *"when I assign this, it points to a different object literal all together."* Need more info. We can't determine the value of `this` from what you posted.

Comment: First, the `var pipe = {}` is overwritten, by the `$A.definePipe('MAppAMDeleter');`, which I assume returns the object you show above, so you can remove the `= {}` part. We still don't know what `this` points to, and you pass the returned object to `$A.machine()`, so we don't know what goes on in there. Could be that the same object created by `definePipe()` is being assigned by `.machine()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
....
initDynamic: function (event) {
    var pipe;
    event.preventDefault();
    pipe = $A.definePipe('MAppAMDeleter');
    pipe.bin.arg_this = event.target;                  // edited here.
    pipe.bin.arcmark_id = this.id;
    $A.machine(pipe);
}, ....
```

The reason is, that `this` can be overwritten by the time the javascript parser tries to fetch the object. different browsers handle JavaScript in (slightly) different ways, so one could be slightly faster fetching the clicked-object, whereas another one could be slower and read `this` as the latest class in charge ;)

`event.target` always points to the clicked object, no matter what ;)

Comment: ...by the time JavaScript fetches which object?

Comment: my fault.. less fetching more parsing ;) the javascript engine of the browser tries to evaluate the code, you add to your page, therefor it needs to "remember" what goes where, and if you try to reference an object (registered as `this`) it has to make a connection to the actual object if the javascript engine is fast and smart enough to detect the clicked object BEFORE another this-referenced object is loaded you end up with the correct object in arg_this, but if some other class has been loaded in that time `this` is already overwritten by the time the javascript engine reads it